# Preventing child nodes from being removed in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I am running into a painful issue with Firebase security.

I would like an authenticated user to create children under a child node however not be allowed to delete any of the children.

Please see comments in 'used' node

security rules below:

```
"users": {

      "$userid":{

      ".read": "$userid === auth.uid",  

      ".write":" $userid === auth.uid && newData.exists()",

       //writeable by user
      "qrcodevalue":{}, 
      "datesubscribed":{},

      //not writeable by user
      "confirmed":{".validate":false}, 
      "issubscribed":{".validate":false},
      "periodend":{".validate":false},
      "stripeid":{".validate":false}, 
      "stripesubscription":{".validate":false}, 
      "subscriptionstatus":{".validate":false}, 

      //user should be able to create children under this node but not delete
      "used":{
        "$promotionid":{
          "dateused":{}
        }
      }, 


      }   
    },
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Firebase security documentation on new and existing data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-data-variables):

> The predefined data variable is used to refer to the data before a write operation takes place. Conversely, the newData variable contains the new data that will exist if the write operation is successful. newData represents the merged result of the new data being written and existing data.
>
> To illustrate, consider a rule that would allow us to create new records or delete existing ones, as long as data does not already exist at a given path, but not to make changes to the data:

```
// we can write as long as old data or new data does not exist
// in other words, if this is a delete or a create, but not an update
".write": "!data.exists() || !newData.exists()"
```

So for you that would translate to something like this:

```
  //user should be able to create children under this node but not delete
  "used":{
    "$promotionid":{
      "dateused":{
        ".write": "newData.exists()"
      }
    }
  },
```

This allows the user to write any data to the node, but not delete it.

If you want them to only *create* but **not** change the data, it becomes:

```
        ".write": "!data.exists() && newData.exists()"
```

Comment: Hi Frank,
Thanks for taking the time to reply. I have tried that however it doesn't work. I can run remove operations for children under the 'used' node. The issue I think is the parent write rule is taking over. When I delete the parent write rule of "$userid === auth.uid && newData.exists()" and then add what you suggested  ".write": "newData.exists()" to 'dateused' then it prevents me from running a remove. The parent rule over throws it because I think the snapshot of the new data has data (even though a child has been deleted).

Comment: Ah, yes. I missed that part of your rules. Indeed: once you've granted a permission on a level, you cannot take it away lower in the tree. This typically means that you should structure our data differently, pulling `used` up to its own "top" level; that way it can have its own set of rules.